# Devise invitable - skip current_password in invitation action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise, devise-invitable

**Case one:**
 When I send invitation email, and user **accept invitation** he need to update own password with fields `:password` and `:confirm_password`
Okay everything works fine.

**config/initializers/devise_auth_token.rb**

```
  # By default sending current password is not needed for the password update.
  # Uncomment to enforce current_password param to be checked before all
  # attribute updates. Set it to :password if you want it to be checked only if
  # password is updated.
  config.check_current_password_before_update = :attributes
```

**Case two:**
 When I login as a user, and I need to change my password, I put the next fields `:current_password`, `:password`, `:password_confirmation`

In this case, **the Case one** didn't work, because he need to put `:current_password`, how I can resolve this problem?

in both cases, we use the route

```
 PUT      /v1/auth/password(.:format)            devise_token_auth/passwords#update
```

How I can avoid `:current_password`, when user accept invitation and set a new password, and allow to set `:current_password` when user just want change own password?

```
module Api::V1
  class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
    include InvitableMethods
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :create
    before_action :resource_from_invitation_token, only: [:edit, :update]

    def create
      User.invite!(invite_params, current_user)
      render json: { success: ['User created.'] }, status: :created
    end

    def edit
      redirect_to "#{client_api_url}?invitation_token=#{params[:invitation_token]}"
    end

    def update
      user = User.accept_invitation!(accept_invitation_params)
      if @user.errors.empty?
        render json: { success: ['User updated.'] }, status: :accepted
      else
        render json: { errors: user.errors.full_messages },
               status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private

    def invite_params
      params.permit(user: [:email, :invitation_token, :provider, :skip_invitation])
    end

    def accept_invitation_params
      params.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token)
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'api/V1/welcome#home'
  scope module: 'api' do
    namespace :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:invitations]
      devise_for :users, path: 'auth', only: [:invitations],
                 controllers: { invitations: 'api/v1/invitations' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @TomLord Do you mean, in my case I need to validate `:current_password`?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry, I mis-read the question slightly. Could you not solve the problem by skipping `current_password` validation if (and only if) `confirmed_at` is nil? Also, I suppose you need the option: `config.check_current_password_before_update = :password`, not `:attributes`.

Comment: @TomLord I'll try, and reply! thanks!